# Ball Tree and Pseudometrics

Tags: scikit-learn, k-nn, metric

The [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) for `sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric` state that

> in order to be used within the BallTree, the distance must be a true metric

(i.e. be non-negative, 0 only if objects are equal, symmetric, and satisfy triangle inequality). My question is, how strict are those requirements? More specifically, would ball tree work for pseudometric (may be 0 for non-equal objects but satisfies other conditions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* a pseudometric should be fine.

The BallTree's ability to limit the number of distances to compute relies heavily on the triangle inequality, and (perhaps to a lesser extent) symmetry.  And nonnegativity certainly seems critical.  At the very least, the code in `sklearn` will probably in places tacitly assume symmetry and nonnegativity.

In a pseudometric, the relation "distance 0" is an equivalence relation, and the distance naturally extends to the quotient space, where it is an honest metric.  So I think for BallTrees, it really shouldn't matter; any ball that contains a given point will also automatically contain all its "equivalent" points.